# Powershell - delete folder if name exists in text file

Tags: powershell, compare

I have a text file with a list of folder name.

I want to delete the folders from my directory for which the name appears in the text file

Here is my try

```
#I get the contents of the text file

$textfile = Get-Content "C:\Users\s611284\Desktop\Dossiers.txt"

#I get the name of the folders from the directory

$Foldersname = Get-ChildItem -Path $Directory | ForEach-Object { 
        $_.BaseName 
      } 

#I get the names present in the text file and in the folders of the directory

Compare-Object -IncludeEqual $textfile $Foldersname | Where-Object SideIndicator -eq '=='
```

93 / 5 000

This gives me the list of folder names present in the text file and in the directory. Now I would like to delete folders present in this list

Hope someone can help

Thank you

Comment: PLEASE do not post images of data/errors/code. why? lookee ... Why should I not upload images of code/data/errors when asking a question? - Meta Stack Overflow — https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-should-i-not-upload-images-of-code-data-errors-when-asking-a-question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use

```
#I get the contents of the text file

$textfile = Get-Content "C:\Users\s611284\Desktop\Dossiers.txt"

#I get the name of the folders from the directory

$Foldersname = Get-ChildItem -Path $Directory | ForEach-Object { 
        $_.BaseName 
      } 

#I get the names present in the text file and in the folders of the directory

Compare-Object -IncludeEqual $textfile $Foldersname | Where-Object SideIndicator -eq '=='|ForEach-Object {

    $item=$_.inputobject
    remove-item $Directory\$item -Recurse  
    
}
```

Answer (score 1):

A shorter way is this:

```
$filenames = Get-Content -Path ".\deleteFolders.txt"
foreach ($file in $filenames) {
    Remove-Item -Force -Path "./$file"
}
```

Note that you have to be inside the folder that contains the folders that you want to delete.